# re submitting all the vales after refreshing a page in php

Tags: php, html

I have a php form. Here i included the action page on the top and the action is php self. i have submitted the page and got the submit message. But when i refresh that page( using f5) again the pge re submitted. how i avoid this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's none standard way to submit a form to itself.
You have to have an extra file that will process your data and then return to your main page.

extra file:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $done = 1;
} else $done = 0;
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?done=$done");
```

also you can use :

```
header('Refresh: 5; URL="mainpage.php"');
```

if you have to post data to itself.

Answer (score 0):

use `CAPTCHA` for this see below link

http://www.quicksolutionproviders.com/php/how-to-stop-form-resubmission-on-page-refresh-in-php/

Comment: `$_POST['submit']` will also be set when you hit `F5` if it is in the previous form too! ;-)

Comment: @thedom Yes, but the Captcha will have changed so the 2nd time the submit will fail. This solution will however stop working if the user opens two tabs on your site at once and starts browsing in each one, as both tabs will save to the same session variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozen possibilities how to do that - here just the first few which came into my mind:

- hashing the input including timestamp and save that in database and check in a function if hash already exists
- forward to another site after the input `header('Location: another-site.php')`...
- save (temporary) IP, browser and timestamp and check if the re-submit is within the allowed time
- a CAPTCHA ...
- a combination of the things mentioned above

It depends on what fits you best ;-).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to redirect to a "recipt" page either with header('location:' or if you're uploading files, with echo '[script]document.location = '...'

IE buggy when redir on multipart-form-data..

regards,

//t

Answer (score 0):

We use

```
header("Location: ORIGINALURL"); 
die();
```

After submitting a form.

However, some webbrowsers will ignore a redirect to the same URL and then the refresh problem remains.

So we use:

```
header("Location: ORIGINALURL?timestamp=".time());
die();
```

Now the URLs will be unique and the page will redirect.

I didn't know IE was buggy on multipart-form-data (thanks @user247245), I will have to look into that.

Comment: And yes, in theory if someone fills in the form really really quickly it won't be unique but for now we decided that that is so unbelievably rare we wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to prevent accidental reduplication, you can use the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).